# Overwrite inline style

Tags: html, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm giving the below style to CSS file to overwrite the `z-index` of control but it is not working. What's wrong with this code? How to overwrite the `ajaxToolkit`'s inline style with `!important`?

`.aspx` page

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender id="mpeOptions" runat="server" 
            popupcontrolid="PanelOptions" targetcontrolid="btnShowOptions" 
            cancelcontrolid="btnCloseOptions" backgroundcssclass="modalBackground"
/>
```

`css` page

```
.modalBackground[style] {
    z-index: 300 !important;
}
```

Runtime converts it to

```
<div    class="modalBackground" 
        id="AccordionPaneStep3_content_mpeOptions_backgroundElement" 
        style="left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none; position: fixed; 
        z-index: 10000;"
/>
```

Comment: remove the `[style]` from your css selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Just remove the [style] in your style.css

Comment: Why all the suggestions to remove the `[style]` attribute selector? The element *has* a style attribute so it is going to match!

Comment: Removing `[style]` will not make a difference, also how do you know is not working its not even displayed.

Comment: removing the [style] is not working. It was my first try.

Comment: Your [code is working](http://jsbin.com/IqowikUs/1/). Your problem is either caused by something you haven't shown us, or doesn't exist and you are measuring the z-index incorrectly.

Comment: <joke>@htcdmrl: there is **nothing** wrong with _you_, it just the code :P</joke>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working one...

```
 .parentclasses .modalBackground
 {
    z-index: 300 !important;
    position: fixed !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me. Can you please include your parent class(es) in the question? Just to see where the <div> element is nested. So other people with the same issue will understand where they have too look for the error.

Answer (score 2):

when ever using zindex need positoin absolute or relative or fixed

```
.modalBackground[style]
   {
    z-index: 300 !important;
    position:relative !important; or
     position:absolute !important;
   }
```

Comment: didn't worked :( I don't know why but it is not affecting inline style of control.

Comment: Try making this rule more specific, so [parent] .modelBackground[style]